# How can we be sure that the tensor identity $\partial_{\mu}\phi^*\partial^{\mu}\phi -\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi^* = 0 $ is true?

Tags: tensors

Consider the complex scaler field $\phi$.

Why is it that the tensor identity $$\partial_{\mu}\phi^*\partial^{\mu}\phi -\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi^*  = 0 $$
is true.

I thought the fact that we specify up and down indices is important and we cannot just assume that swapping them will allow for such an identity to hold.

Furthermore how can we tell that $\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi^* = -\phi^*\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\phi$

This is probably quite obvious I am just a little confused.

Comment: Is this a classical field?

Comment: I believe so that this is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\phi$ is a classical field. Recall that $\partial_\mu$ denotes the covariant derivative, meaning $\partial_\mu = (\partial_0, \partial_1,\partial_2, \partial_3)$ and $\partial^\mu = g^{\mu \nu}\partial_\nu$ (contract in the $\nu$ variable) where $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse metric. For simplicity, take $g = \eta$ to be the Minkowski metric with signature $(-, +, +, +)$ then it follows that
$\partial^\mu = (-\partial_0, \partial_1, \partial_2, \partial_3).$ Finally, we see that
\begin{align}
\partial^\mu\phi^\ast \cdot \partial_\mu \phi =&\ (-\partial_0\phi^\ast, \partial_1\phi^\ast, \partial_2\phi^\ast, \partial_3\phi^\ast)\cdot (\partial_0\phi, \partial_1\phi, \partial_2\phi, \partial_3\phi) \\
=&\  (\partial_0\phi, \partial_1\phi, \partial_2\phi, \partial_3\phi)\cdot (-\partial_0\phi^\ast, \partial_1\phi^\ast, \partial_2\phi^\ast, \partial_3\phi^\ast)\\
=&\ \partial_\mu\phi \cdot \partial^\mu\phi^\ast.
\end{align}

Also, it is not true that
\begin{align}
\partial^\mu\phi^\ast \cdot \partial_\mu \phi= -\phi^\ast \partial^\mu\partial_\mu \phi
\end{align}
since the left hand side only involves first order derivatives whereas the right hand side involves second order derivatives. However, it is true that
\begin{align}
\int\ \partial^\mu\phi^\ast \cdot \partial_\mu \phi= -\int\ \phi^\ast \partial^\mu\partial_\mu \phi
\end{align}
because of integration by parts.

Comment: I'm rusty with such manipulations, but it seems like the former derivation ought to be simpler: The metric tensor is symmetric, so$$\partial^\mu \phi^*\cdot \partial_\mu \phi = g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \phi\cdot \partial_\mu \phi=\partial_\nu \phi^* \cdot g^{\nu \mu}\partial_\mu \phi=\partial_\nu \phi^* \partial^\nu \phi.$$

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes. However, it seems like the OP is not too comfortable with these symbol pushing techniques.

Comment: Ahh it makes sense...but could you go through the integration of parts bit in a bit more detail. But thank you for the detail in the first section it really clarified stuff!

Comment: Remember that $\int u' v' dx = - \int u'' v dx$ if the boundary terms disappear. Note that I am not saying $u'v' = -u''v$.